# Chrome Extension - Load popup at page bottom (not in top right corner)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Now, I now how to make an extension that drops down in a small window at the top right of the page beneath the extension icons. **But how can I create a new div at the bottom of the web page, like this buzzgrowl extension: http://buzzgrowl.com/**?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about a webkit notifications ?

```
window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('instantMessage.html', 'POPUP').show();
```

If you really want a popup from the extension icon, then you need to use this :

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

I suggest you to read this page : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

It will probably be better explain then me ;)